# Xamarin.Forms Working with data (Best DataBase Connection)

Tags: database, rest, xamarin.forms, .net-7.0

I'm developing a Xamarin .Forms App  , don;t judge..

I would like to store the data which contains,  @>  Users   /   Article   /   Sound  (Podcasts)    /   Posts (Forum)   etc.

First thing,  I haven't been developing VS since VB ,  so after covered C# OOP and XAML  /  Xamarin  .Forms,    I don't know which Database (form) is best to approach to store.

Second      ,  is I don't know how to connect to the app,  by looking I see many different options.

to summarize  - What's best to connect Xamarin  . Forms App and a database   in terms of performance and security   (my app contains some vulnerable data and promises discretion to the users).   Best option with expanded documentation or understandable explanation.
Also   (If I can include in this question how to do the signing (and manage the user group))
Thanks in Advance.   . Evgeny

**   The options that I saw are Local DataBase SQLite  ; Which I don't know if I need for the project (If I use a DataBase)  ,  and MySQL   /MSSQL   or  other Database  with RESTAPI . .   **

Comment: I actually need a remote,  BUT I was wondering shall shall if I use both..?

Comment: We can't answer that for you.  If you are using a remote database, you need to build a [webservice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/) layer.  You should never connect directly from a client app to a remote database

Comment: Can't answer, why?   My question is about which one is the best way and how can it be implemented? (in xamarin. Forms)

Comment: I can try to make a list of questions : 
.
1= What is the best Remote DataBase to use with Xamarin. Forms?
1A=  What is the best way of storing data such as Posts /  User Information etc.
2= How to do the signing ( same way or.. .. .)
3= Should I also use a local database and store a big chunk ( for example download forum topics)   there?
4= How to connect to that database inside  Xamarin  .Forms and how to make all the necessary?

Comment: "best" is a matter of opinion and depends on your requirements.  Those sorts of questions are explicitly off-topic on SO.  There are a huge number of existing questions, posts, tutorials, videos, etc about working with databases in XF.  Please read [ask] for guidance on what is considered on-topic